# Filter selection on cut/copy with javascript?

Tags: javascript, copy

On one of my sites, I used **&shy;** liberally to provide better hyphenation in the web browser.  Unfortunately, they get corrupted by copying or cutting and pasting, so when people copy from my website, the ar-tic-les ap-pear with ex-tra hy-phens which are really annoying.  I exaggerated it a bit here, but you get the idea.

I'd love a way to filter the selection on copy - basically an opportunity to remove the &shy;'s before they get to the clipboard.  **I suspect this isn't possible,** based on what I've read/researched, but thought I'd ask the collective wisdom here, in case I've missed something.

A pseudocode example of what would be beautiful:

```
element.oncopy = function (ev) {
    ev.selection.replace(/&shy;/g, '');
    return true; // or ev, I suppose
}
```

Comment: How about `<wbr />` instead? Here is an interesting article http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html

Comment: `<wbr />` doesn't provide hyphens at the word breaks, which is necessary for English.  I could use create a hyphen via css using `wbr:after { content: '-' }` but then you can't distinguish between `<wbr />`s that are and aren't being used, so may as well just use hyphens.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I assumed you would get a hyphen my apologies . http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this article about the `oncopy` event.  I think it is exactly what you need: http://help.dottoro.com/ljwexqxl.php.

Example #2 on the following page explains how to use the clipboard in a cross-browser friendly way (since only IE has access to the `clipboardData` object used in the first article): http://help.dottoro.com/ljxundda.php

That page also mentions that there are some cases where security restrictions may prevent the cross-browser method from working, which is why some sites use Flash to manipulate the clipboard.  Here's an article which discusses that method, in case it sounds like what you want: http://www.jeffothy.com/weblog/clipboard-copy/

**EDIT**

Have a look at [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).  It is a JavaScript method of hyphenating text intelligently on the client side.  Quickly playing around with the demo ([which can be found here](http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%203.2.0/WorkingExample.html)), it appears to leave the hyphens out of copied text.  It might be a pain to change your content to use this instead of `&shy;`, but it looks like it will achieve all of your goals.

Comment: I saw this too, before asking. I couldn't get the code to work on Chrome, and Googling suggests that execCommand isn't a dependable bet.  Have you had success with this approach?

Comment: Not really.  I think the Flash option is the *most* dependable, but you can't even really count on that, since some users may not have the plug-in installed/enabled, or they may be copying from an iOS browser, etc.  Have a look at the updated section of my answer, it may be of some interest.

Comment: Will definitely look into that.  I'm currently doing the hyphenation server-side, but this may make it worth doing client-side, or I can try to figure out how it gets the clients to be excluded from copying.

Comment: woah, that is a big script :)